# What regular expression would match the first email + 1st comma/nothing [PHP]?

Tags: php, regex

I have the following examples:

```
$ex1 = '123456@gmail.com,abc@yahoo.com';
$ex2 = '123456@gmail.com';
$result = preg_replace('/123456@gmail.com/','',$ex1); //$ex1 or $ex1
```

The $result would be empty for $ex2, which is good. However, it doesnt remove comma when $ex1 is used (for $ex1, the $result should be 'abc@yahoo.com'). Please help. Basically, it should also match comma if there is comma after the string '123456@gmail.com'.

Comment: Could `123456@gmail.com` appear anywhere in your comma separated list or is it always first? Can there be more than 2 elements?

Comment: /123456@gmail.com,\*/ (\* matches 0 or more of preceding token)

Comment: 123456@gmail.com will always be the first, and there can be no/more emails after it.

Comment: @hank , Thank you very much. It works!

Answer (score -1):

Use this one it should work

```
$result = preg_replace('/(123456@gmail.com)?[ ,]+/','',$ex1);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I really need to do it just once (in a single line) with one regex

Comment: $result = preg_replace('/(123456@gmail.com)?[ ,]+/','',$ex1);